# Passing Values in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm a newbie to Angular JS. I've created a form in my index.html page, when I fill the details in the form and press submit, it should redirect to details.html page. Where I can able to show the details filled on the form.

**HTML**

```
  <html>
  <script src="angular.min.js"> </script>
  <script src="script.js"> </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="FormApp">
  <div class="forms" ng-controller="CustomerDetailsController">
    <form novalidate>
      First Name:<br>
      <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" required/>
      <br>
      <br>
      Last Name:<br>
      <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
      <br>
      <br>
      Age:<br>
      <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
      <br>
      <br>
      Email :<br>
      <input type="email" ng-model="lastName">
      <br>
      <br>
      Location<br>
      <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
      <br>
      <br>
      <button ng-click="submit()">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
var FormApp = angular.module('FormApp', []);
FormApp.controller('CustomerDetailsController', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function() {

    }
}]);
```

What will be the best way to do this? Any help would appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You need lot to learn dear follow this  https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial"" hope it will help.
But for submit a form and getting a response you need server side code as well and if you just want to redirect to another form and need the previous form data then you should learn routing and how to manage routing params.
But I am suggesting you to first follow some good tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding angular routing to your application which need `ngRoute` dependency. Then you need to define one parent controller that can hold the partial views common data like here it is `mainCtrl`.

Apart from that you missed few things while you created a form, form should have its `name` attribute so that angular will create a scope variable of that form and internally manages `form` validity inside that scope variable like `$valid`, `$error`, etc. Then the same `name` should be given to each form element, if you don't declare the `name` attribute, then it won't consider it as form element.

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div class="forms">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CODE**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/view1', {
      templateUrl: 'view1.html',
      controller: 'CustomerDetailsController'
    })
    .when('/view2', {
      templateUrl: 'view2.html',
      controller: 'form2Ctrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/view1'
    });
});
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.form = {};
});

app.controller('CustomerDetailsController', function($scope,$location) {
  $scope.submit = function(){
    if($scope.form1.$valid)
      $location.path('/view2');
  };
});

app.controller('form2Ctrl', function($scope,$location) {
  //this controller contain the data which will you get from
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ThklIevuTPmPSwHMcimC?p=preview)

**Update**

**Clearing confusion of on what `form2Ctrl` will contain as per request by @user3440121.**

The second view may contain a ajax call that will fetch the user information from server and display it on the view or it can be any show the list of employees, Its depend on the whats the requirement of your application.
Basically you should not store data on client side as i did stored the data in form object and accessing it on `view2` directly as I can access parent scope variable. I shown this only for demonstration purpose. In actual implementation we will take `$route` parameter from the URL & the we will make an ajax call to server which give data back to you. Currently in plunkr we redirecting to `view2` using `$location.path('/view2');` that would change to `$location.path('/edit/1')` and you need to add route to your `app.config` like

**Route**

```
.when('/edit/:id', {
   templateUrl: 'view2.html',
   controller: 'form2Ctrl'
})
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('form2Ctrl', function($scope,$route) {
   //we can get id here from $route object
   console.log($route.params.id); //here it will be `id` which `1` in the URL
   //now you have id you can make ajax to server and get required data
});
```

Hope above information cleared all the doubts about the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. it was truly professional and simple way one could understand this. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: i have little confusion regarding the form2Ctrl working. can you please explain it too?

Answer (score 0):

Your `$scope.submit` function has nothing inside it for routing.

It should be:

```
$scope.submit = function($scope) { 
  $scope.$apply(function() { 
    $location.path("*place your details page here*"); 
  });
}
```

Note that you also need to inject $location to your controller, as follows:

```
FormApp.controller('CustomerDetailsController', 
  ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) ...
```

Try reading the following for more details:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Also have you tried checking your paths? (e.g. *angular.min.js*, *script.js*)