# how to send the data of a ng-controller to another jsp page when click on send button?

Tags: angularjs

Here i will add the product data from response of http for myctrl then when i click on checkout i have to bind all this information and send it to another jsp page in that page i have to get the response data.How can i achieve it by using angularjs. please help me out

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <div ng-repeat="x in names">
      <div>Product Name : {{x.itemname}}</div>
       <div>Qty : {{x.itemQty}}</div>
    <div>Price : {{x.itemQty}}</div>
    <div>Total : {{x.itemQty}}</div> 
    </div>
    <div><button ng-click="checkOut()" >CheckOut</button></div>
    </div>
<script>
angular.module("MyApp",[])
.controller("MyCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('responseData.html').success(function(response) {
            $scope.names= response;
          });
}]);
</script>
```

Comment: are you redirecting to other page, or only changing the view using angular route?

Comment: i have to redirect to another page with all this data and i have to receive all the data in new page @pankaj

Comment: Then you need save those values to server(db) & on another page you can get that record by using id `$http.get`, why you don't use angular routing

Comment: To save the data in db i need to send the all data to another page.

Comment: Instead of redirecting user to different page, you should show him different view on click of button, use angular routing that will  help you..

Comment: Ok fine i will try this.can you please send me example for this if you have aby?

Comment: check the answer added by me also do check the reference link..for more info with working fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to persist the any object/value on client side, I'd suggest you to don't redirect the user to other page.

Instead do create a SPA, add route based view to your application. For implementing such a powerful SAP you could use `angular-route` API designed by angular team **OR** you could also use `ui.router` which is developed by `angular-ui` team. Suppose you choose `angular-route` here then, show different view on different routes, you need to configure you route in angular config phase using `$routeProvider` & then load view and controller for partial  view. In your case it would be confirmation submit page on click of button.

You could have one wrapper `div` on your `ng-view` directive and then give `mainCtrl` controller to it. That will act as a sharing component amongest your various views.

**HTML**

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/view1', {
      templateUrl: 'view1.html',
      controller: 'CustomerDetailsController'
    })
    .when('/view2', {
      templateUrl: 'view2.html',
      controller: 'form2Ctrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/view1'
    });
});

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.form = {}; //this is global and thats why it can be available on any view
});

app.controller('CustomerDetailsController', function($scope,$location) {
  $scope.submit = function(){
    if($scope.form1.$valid)
      $location.path('/view2');
  };
});

app.controller('form2Ctrl', function($scope,$location) {
  //this controller contain the data which will you get from
});
```

Preferable approach for sharing a data would be using singleton `service/factory` in your application.

**HTML**

```
<div class="forms">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>

app.service('sharedData', function() {
   var sharedData = this;
   sharedData.myData = {};
});

app.controller('CustomerDetailsController', function($scope,$location, sharedData) {
  $scope.submit = function(){
    sharedData.myData.formData = $scope.form1Data; //form1Data will have form1Data
    if($scope.form1.$valid)
      $location.path('/view2');
  };
});

app.controller('form2Ctrl', function($scope,$location, sharedData) {
  console.log(sharedData); //this will have the data shared from the CustomerDetailsController
});
```

For more info Refer this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28657470/2435473), Thanks.